# How to obtain gcloud predictions by passing a base64 image to a retrained inception model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to obtain a prediction with gcloud by passing a base64 encoded image to a retrained inception model, by using a similar approach as the one adopted by [Davide Biraghi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7219743/davide-biraghi) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261701/how-make-correct-predictions-of-jpeg-image-in-cloud-ml) post.
When using `'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'` as input I also get the same error when trying to get predictions, therefore I adopted a slightly different approach.

Following [rhaertel80](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1399222/rhaertel80)'s suggestions in his answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849195/how-convert-a-jpeg-image-into-json-file-in-google-machine-learning), I have created a graph that takes a jpeg image as input in `'B64Connector/input'`, preprocess it and feeds it to the inception model in `'ResizeBilinear:0'`.

The prediction returns the values, although the wrong ones (I am trying to find a solution in another post) but at least it doesn't fail. The placeholder I use as input is

```
images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=(None,), name='B64Connector/input')
```

And I add it to the model inputs with

```
inputs = {"b64_bytes": 'B64Connector/input:0'}
tf.add_to_collection("inputs", json.dumps(inputs))
```

As Davide I am following the suggestions found in these posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849195/how-convert-a-jpeg-image-into-json-file-in-google-machine-learning), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978526/deploy-retrained-inception-model-on-google-cloud-machine-learning) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-train-and-classify-images-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow) and I am trying to get predictions with

```
    gcloud beta ml predict --json-instances=request.json --model=MODEL
```

where the file `request.json` has been obtained with this code

```
jpgtxt = base64.b64encode(open(imagefile ,"rb").read())

with open( outputfile, 'w' ) as f :
  f.write( json.dumps( {"b64_bytes": {"b64": jpgtxt}} ) )
```

I would like to know why the prediction fails when I use as input `'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'` and it doesn't when I use this different approach, since they look almost identical to me: I use the same script to generate the instances (changing the input_key) and the same command line to request predictions

Is there a way to pass the instance fed to `'B64Connector/input:0'` to `'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'` in order to get the right predictions?

Comment: To clarify, are you using the code from the blog post or your own code? Can you post relevant pieces of code that use the images_placeholder?

Comment: Actually I am using a slightly customized version of the code from a post you wrote here on stackoverflow. I'll post the code right away!

Comment: Also, can you say more about why the blog post doesn't meet your needs? I haven't quite figured out what extra functionality your customization is providing

Answer (score 2):

Here I describe more in detail my approach and how I use the images_placeholder.

I define a function that resizes the image:

```
  def decode_and_resize(image_str_tensor):
    """Decodes jpeg string, resizes it and returns a uint8 tensor."""

    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_str_tensor, channels=MODEL_INPUT_DEPTH)

    # Note resize expects a batch_size, but tf_map supresses that index,
    # thus we have to expand then squeeze.  Resize returns float32 in the
    # range [0, uint8_max]
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
    image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(
        image, [MODEL_INPUT_HEIGHT, MODEL_INPUT_WIDTH], align_corners=False)
    image = tf.squeeze(image, squeeze_dims=[0])
    image = tf.cast(image, dtype=tf.uint8)
    return image
```

and one that generates the definition of the graph in which the resize takes place and where `images_placeholder` is defined and used

```
def create_b64_graph() :
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as b64_graph:

    images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=(None,),
                                     name='B64Connector/input')
    decoded_images = tf.map_fn(
        decode_and_resize, images_placeholder, back_prop=False, dtype=tf.uint8)

    # convert_image_dtype, also scales [0, uint8_max] -> [0, 1).
    images = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(decoded_images, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Finally, rescale to [-1,1] instead of [0, 1)
    images = tf.sub(images, 0.5)
    images = tf.mul(images, 2.0)

    # NOTE: using identity to get a known name for the output tensor.
    output = tf.identity(images, name='B64Connector/output')

    b64_graph_def = b64_graph.as_graph_def()

    return b64_graph_def
```

Moreover I am using the following code to merge the resizing graph with the inception graph. Can I use a similar approach to link `images_placeholder` directly to `'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'`?

```
def concatenate_to_inception_graph( b64_graph_def ):

  model_dir = INPUT_MODEL_PATH
  model_filename = os.path.join(
       model_dir, 'classify_image_graph_def.pb')

  with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Import the b64_graph and get its output tensor
    resized_b64_tensor, = (tf.import_graph_def(b64_graph_def, name='',
                             return_elements=['B64Connector/output:0']))

    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
      inception_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
      inception_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

      # Concatenate b64_graph and inception_graph
      g_1 = tf.import_graph_def(inception_graph_def, name='inception',
               input_map={'ResizeBilinear:0' : resized_b64_tensor} )

    return sess.graph
```